# Estacionamiento en Java: Obtener el carro con mayor tiempo estacionado

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un proyecto sobre un parqueadero, en uno de los métodos debo retornar la placa del carro que lleva más tiempo en el parqueadero y si hay varios carros, deberá retornar cualquiera de ellos.

Este es el código, pero me retorna el último carro que ingresa. ¿Cómo puedo arreglarlo?

```java
public String metodo1() {
    String placa = "";
    int hora = 0;
    for (Puesto p : puestos){
        if (p.estaOcupado()){
            Carro c = puestos[p.darNumeroPuesto()].darCarro();
            if (c.darTiempoEnParqueadero(horaActual) > hora){
                placa = c.darPlaca();
            }
        }
    }
    return "El carro " + placa + " lleva más tiempo en el parqueadero.";
}
```

Esta es la clase puesto que estoy utilizando en el método

```java
public class Puesto {
    private Carro carro;
    private int numeroPuesto;
    public Puesto(int pPuesto) {
        carro = null;
        numeroPuesto = pPuesto;
    }
    public Carro darCarro() {
        return carro;
    }
    public boolean estaOcupado() {
        boolean ocupado = carro != null;
        return ocupado;
    }
    public void parquearCarro(Carro pCarro) {
        carro = pCarro;
    }
    public void sacarCarro() {
        carro = null;
    }
    public int darNumeroPuesto() {
        return numeroPuesto;
    }
    public boolean tieneCarroConPlaca(String pPlaca) {
        boolean tieneCarro = true;
        if (carro == null) {
            tieneCarro = false;
        }
        else if (carro.tienePlaca(pPlaca)) {
            tieneCarro = true;
        }
        else {
            tieneCarro = false;
        }
        return tieneCarro;
    }
}
```

y la clase carro
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias por la respuesta

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar la clase puesto? Para saber más o menos cómo lo estás manejando

Comment: @EduardoJiménez claro que sí, ya lo pongo

Comment: pon el código como texto por favor

Comment: Pon `hora` en el mayor valor posible: `int hora = Integer.MAX_VALUE;` y compara directamente las horas de llegada. Cuando encuentres una hora menor a `hora` reemplázala y también su placa. No hacen falta cálculos para saber cuanto tiempo lleva un carro en el parqueadero. El que tenga la hora menor registrada será el que lleve más tiempo en el parqueadero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En metodo1(), por cada auto estás ejecutando la comparacion:

```
 if (c.darTiempoEnParqueadero(horaActual) > hora)
```

que usa la variable hora cuyo valor es siempre 0:

```
int hora = 0;
```

Entonces cualquier auto con un tiempo mayor a 0 cumple la condicion, **hasta el último del arreglo**.

Puedes solucionar el problema de la siguiente forma:
Por cada puesto ocupado, revisar si el auto en ese puesto lleva mas tiempo que algun maximo registrado por otro puesto ocupado. Si es así, actualiza la variable máximo y conserva la placa:

```
public String metodo1() {
   String placa = "";
   int tiempoMaximo = 0;
   for (Puesto p : puestos){
       if (p.estaOcupado()){
           Carro c = puestos[p.darNumeroPuesto()].darCarro();
           if (c.darTiempoEnParqueadero(horaActual) > tiempoMaximo){
               tiempoMaximo= c.darTiempoEnParqueadero(horaActual);
               placa = c.darPlaca();
           }
       }
   }
   return "El carro " + placa + " lleva más tiempo en el parqueadero.";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## Recomendaciones

Empezamos con las recomendaciones puesto que estructurar bien tu proyecto y tu código te ayudará a facilitar el trabajo, descuida, esto lo iras aprendiendo con la experiencia.

Para facilitar el manejo te recomendaría aprender y usar las estructuras de datos. Entre ellas están los ***Maps*** de la [interfaz Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html), que ayudan a asociar llaves con valores; puedes entonces asociar por ejemplo, tu carro a un lugar de estacionamiento. Y como explican en el enlace, un mapa no puede tener llaves duplicadas, lo que nos es conveniente en este caso.

Un ejemplo de cómo se vería un mapa es el siguiente:

| Lugar de estacionamiento | Automóvil estacionado |
| --- | --- |
| 7 | Carro 2 |
| 5 | Carro 3 |
| 8 | Carro 7 |

En este caso el lugar de estacionamiento sería la llave y el valor el automóvil estacionado.

Vemos también que [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html) tiene métodos muy útiles para lo que quieres lograr:

- [*putIfAbscent*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#putIfAbsent(K,V)): Si la llave no existe, entonces coloca la asociación llave-valor
- [*remove*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#remove(java.lang.Object)): Elimina si es que existe la relación llave-valor
- [*get*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#get(java.lang.Object)): Retorna el valor asociado a la llave

**Para horas o fechas siempre utiliza un tipo de dato de Hora o Fecha**

Java tiene la clase [*LocalTime*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html), la cual nos permite registrar un instante del día (hora, minuto, segundo, ms).

También hay otras clases como *LocalDate* y *LocalDateTime*, que sirven para registar fechas (año, mes día), (año, mes, día, hora, minuto, segundo, ms) respectivamente. Y obviamente son mejores para manipular tiempo que los enteros.

Con eso podemos crear un modelo más firme de lo que necesitas:

## Utilizando un [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashMap.html) para una clase "estacionamiento"

**Clase Carro**

```java
public class Car {
    private final String license_plate;
    private final LocalTime check_in;

    public Car(String license_plate, LocalTime check_in) {
        this.license_plate = license_plate;
        this.check_in = check_in;
    }

    public String getLicense_plate() {
        return license_plate;
    }

    public LocalTime getCheck_in() {
        return check_in;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "license_plate: '" + license_plate + "'\t" + "check_in: " + check_in;
    }
}
```

**Clase estacionamiento**

```java
public class ParkingLot {
    private final HashMap<Integer, Car> cars = new HashMap<>();

    /**
     * If the place is available, the car successfully parks
     * and registers data
     * @param car car to park
     * @param parking_place parking place
     * @return the Car if successfully parked, null otherwise
     */
    protected Car parkCar(Car car, Integer parking_place) {
        return cars.putIfAbsent(parking_place, car);
    }

    /**
     * Removes from the Car from the HashMap
     * @param parking_place parking place to remove
     */
    protected void clearParkingLot(Integer parking_place) {
        cars.remove(parking_place);
    }

    /**
     * @param parking_place parking place
     * @return the car parked in the parking place specified
     */
    protected Car getCarFromParkingLot(Integer parking_place) {
        return cars.get(parking_place);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves the parking place from the Car with the SpecifiedId
     * @param license_plate license plates
     * @return null if the car doesn't exist, the parking place value otherwise
     */
    protected Integer getParkingPlaceFromCarId(String license_plate) {
        // for each entry compares if the license plate is equal
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Car> element : cars.entrySet()) {
            if (element.getValue().getLicense_plate().equalsIgnoreCase(license_plate))
                return element.getKey();
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves the parking place from the Car with the SpecifiedId
     * @param car Car to search
     * @return null if the car doesn't exist, the parking place value otherwise
     */
    protected Integer getParkingPlaceFromCar(Car car) {
        return getParkingPlaceFromCarId(car.getLicense_plate());
    }

}
```

## Tu problema

¿Cómo podemos entonces obtener el carro con mayor tiempo estacionado?

Podemos hacerlo de dos maneras:

- La larga: Por cada valor en el *HashMap* acceder al tiempo donde ingresó al estacionamiento y si es el más antigüo, poner ese carro como el mínimo y al final retornar el mínimo.
- La automatizada: Implementando un comparador a la clase ***Car*** (revisa el [tutorial de Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html)) y hallar el mínimo con el método [Collections.min](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#min(java.util.Collection))

Como nos interesa hacerlo lo más sencillo posible, entonces podemos implementar la interfaz [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html) (`implements Comparable<Car>`)

```java
public class Car implements Comparable<Car>{
    private final String license_plate;
    private final LocalTime check_in;
    
    ...
    ...

    public int compareTo(@NotNull Car car) {
        return check_in.compareTo(car.getCheck_in());
    }
}
```

El método se reduce a algo tan sencillo como:

```java
public class ParkingLot {
    private final HashMap<Integer, Car> cars = new HashMap<>();

    ...
    ...

    /**
     * Returns the car with longer time parked
     * @return Car with the min check in time
     */
    protected Car getCarWithLongerParkedTime() {
        return Collections.min(cars.values());
    }
}
```

## Código final

```java
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class StackOverflow {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ParkingLot parkingLot = new ParkingLot();

        parkingLot.parkCar(new Car("A3E567", LocalTime.of(14, 12)), 1);
        parkingLot.parkCar(new Car("ER56TM", LocalTime.of(11,0, 33)), 2);
        parkingLot.parkCar(new Car("J0FD7L", LocalTime.of(12, 15, 12)), 3);

        System.out.println(parkingLot.getCarWithLongerParkedTime());

    }

    private static class ParkingLot {
        private final HashMap<Integer, Car> cars = new HashMap<>();

        /**
         * If the place is available, the car successfully parks
         * and registers data
         * @param car car to park
         * @param parking_place parking place
         * @return the Car if successfully parked, null otherwise
         */
        protected Car parkCar(Car car, Integer parking_place) {
            return cars.putIfAbsent(parking_place, car);
        }

        /**
         * Removes from the Car from the HashMap
         * @param parking_place parking place to remove
         */
        protected void clearParkingLot(Integer parking_place) {
            cars.remove(parking_place);
        }

        /**
         * @param parking_place parking place
         * @return the car parked in the parking place specified
         */
        protected Car getCarFromParkingLot(Integer parking_place) {
            return cars.get(parking_place);
        }

        /**
         * Retrieves the parking place from the Car with the SpecifiedId
         * @param license_plate license plates
         * @return null if the car doesn't exist, the parking place value otherwise
         */
        protected Integer getParkingPlaceFromCarId(String license_plate) {

            for (Map.Entry<Integer, Car> element : cars.entrySet()) {
                if (element.getValue().getLicense_plate().equalsIgnoreCase(license_plate))
                    return element.getKey();
            }
            return null;
        }

        /**
         * Retrieves the parking place from the Car with the SpecifiedId
         * @param car Car to search
         * @return null if the car doesn't exist, the parking place value otherwise
         */
        protected Integer getParkingPlaceFromCar(Car car) {
            return getParkingPlaceFromCarId(car.getLicense_plate());
        }

        /**
         * Returns the car with longer time parked
         * @return Car with the min check in time
         */
        protected Car getCarWithLongerParkedTime() {
            return Collections.min(cars.values());
        }

    }

    private static class Car implements Comparable<Car>{
        private final String license_plate;
        private final LocalTime check_in;

        public Car(String license_plate, LocalTime check_in) {
            this.license_plate = license_plate;
            this.check_in = check_in;
        }

        public String getLicense_plate() {
            return license_plate;
        }

        public LocalTime getCheck_in() {
            return check_in;
        }

        public int compareTo(@NotNull Car car) {
            return check_in.compareTo(car.getCheck_in());
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "license_plate: '" + license_plate + "'\t" + "check_in: " + check_in;
        }
    }
}
```

**Input**

```java
// LocalTime.of(hora, minuto, segundo, ms)

parkingLot.parkCar(new Car("A3E567", LocalTime.of(14, 12)), 1);
parkingLot.parkCar(new Car("ER56TM", LocalTime.of(11,0, 33)), 2);
parkingLot.parkCar(new Car("J0FD7L", LocalTime.of(12, 15, 12)), 3);
```

**Output**

```java
// El carro con mayor tiempo estacionado
license_plate: 'ER56TM' check_in: 11:00:33
```

Comment: Hay algunos usuarios que luego me comentan sobre responder con el nivel del usuario que preguntó, esta respuesta la publico: 1.- Para usuarios en el futuro que tengan una duda similar y tengan esta respuesta como una mejor referencia. 2.- Por si la autora de la pregunta quiere investigar más acerca de esta respuesta para mejorar profesional o escolarmente.